# Can't export Windows 10 EFS certificate

Tags: windows-10, efs

Just got a new laptop and encrypted a couple of folders, the handy "export certificate" reminder popped up, so I exported it. Job done. This reminded me to check I had backed up my other computers' certificates.

I opened CertMgr.msc, went to personal, found the correct certificate and tried to export it.

It gives me a warning that

> the associated private key is  marked as not exportable. Only the certificate can be exported.

and

> Yes, export the private key

is grayed out

When I click next the option to export as "Personal Information Exchange" is grayed out too.

So I'm a bit stuck.

If I can't get it exported, can I decrypt everything, delete the certificate and create a new one? I don't know what else, if anything it is used for.

Thanks

Comment: If you already exported it once I am not sure I understnad the problem.  I wouldn't be removing any certificates until you understand the reason you cannot export the current certificate.

Comment: Just because I exported it once, doesn't mean I still have it. Thus the need to re-export it. The question is, why can't I export it, and how do I get around the restriction.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Private key is missing in your case, please check if there is the EFS related file under C:\Users[Yourname]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA

I have tested on my computer and there is no such issue, I can export with Private key as below:

[image]

Please try to decrypt all EFS files and try to encrypt again.

If this issue still persists, I consider if it is caused by corrupted system componenst, run following commands for further test:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

SFC /scannow
```

Answer (score 0):

All your personal certificates and private keys are located in the following folder:

- %SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

If you don't have access to it and you've admin rights, reassign the *Administrator* account *Full access*.

See: [Can not export private key because the option is greyed out](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/617) at Comodo

Answer (score 0):

This helped me when I had the *Personal Information Exchange* greyed out:

- run `certmgr.msc` as Administrator

  - click the start menu and start typing to find the `certmgr.msc`
  - you need to write the whole name including the `.msc` extension
  - right-click the found program in start menu and select "Run as Administrator"
- then follow the standard proces - the grayed out options should be now available

OR

- run Command Prompt (cmd.exe) as administrator and use following comands

  - `cipher /x d:\path\to\your\backupFile` (no file extension)
  - confirm the popup window
  - type a password used for protecting your EFS certificate, then confirm the password
  - you should see the "EFS certificate(s) is(are) backed up successfully." in command prompt